# Spring Boot: How to change the path to serve static files?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project located in the path "C:\Personal Projects\Spring" and I want it to serve to browser static HTML file named index.html that is placed in "C:\Personal Projects\Game\build".

Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("spring.resources.static-locations",
                "C:\\Personal Projects\\Game\\build");
        app.setDefaultProperties(properties);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

When I run the program and open browser for "localhost:8080/index.html" I get a 404 error.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
properties.setProperty("spring.resources.static-locations",
                "file:C:\\Personal Projects\\Game\\build");
```